# PHP/HTML/JS price form not updating

Tags: javascript, php, calc

I have a problem with a price form (form.php), in which I want to assign to inputs #kd2, #kd4 and #kd6 it makes the price to change, but its not updating actual price (visible). Prices are defined in scripts.js at lines 740-750 and it works for two other inputs (#ko3, #aa1), when I add a third input it doesnt. Please help me.

```
    var mask = $("#aa1").is(":checked");

var price = calcPrice(A, B, C, D);

if(mask)
    price += 90;

if ($('#ko3').attr("checked") == 'checked') {
    price += 190;
}
```

File form.php:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 back-link">
        <div class="link wer2">
          <a href="gallery.php">
            <img src="images/arrow12.png"/>
            Powrót
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 product-title">
          <div class="text-area-dark text-left">
            <h2><?php echo $nameHtml ?></h2>
          </div>
          <?php if ($basePrice != 0): ?>
          <div class="price">
            <h3>Cena bazowa: <?php echo $basePrice ?>zł/dm<sup>2</sup></h3>
          </div>
          <?php else: ?>
          <div class="additional-space"></div>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 calc-information">
          <p>Kalkulator ma na celu przybliżenie Państwu kosztu wybranych drzwiczek wraz z modyfikacjami.</p>
          <p class="orange">Nie jest on równoznaczny z zakupem.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <form id="offer-form" method="POST">
            <h3 class="wt1 first-h3">1. Podaj wymiary (cm)</h3>

            <div class="block sizes">
              <div class="iblock">
                <div class="block">
                  <p class="iblock">Wymiar <strong>A</strong></p>
                  <input id="sizeA" name="sizeA" class="iblock" type="text" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <?php if ($isC && $isD): ?>
              <div class="iblock" style="margin-left:60px;">
                <div class="block">
                  <p class="iblock">Wymiar <strong>C</strong></p>
                  <input id="sizeC" name="sizeC" class="iblock" type="text" style="margin-left: 12px;" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php elseif($isC && !$isD): ?>
              <div class="iblock" style="margin-left:60px;">
                <div class="block">
                  <p class="iblock">Wymiar <strong>B</strong></p>
                  <input id="sizeB" name="sizeB" class="iblock" type="text" style="margin-left: 11px;" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="block sizes">
              <?php if ($isC && !$isD): ?>
              <div class="iblock">
                <div class="block">
                  <p class="iblock">Wymiar <strong>C</strong></p>
                  <input id="sizeC" name="sizeC" class="iblock" type="text" style="margin-left: 12px;" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php else: ?>
              <div class="iblock">
                <div class="block">
                  <p class="iblock">Wymiar <strong>B</strong></p>
                  <input id="sizeB" name="sizeB" class="iblock" type="text" style="margin-left: 11px;" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php endif; ?>

              <?php if ($isD): ?>
              <div class="iblock " style="margin-left:60px;">
                <div class="block">
                  <p class="iblock">Wymiar <strong>D</strong></p>
                  <input id="sizeD" name="sizeD" class="iblock" type="text" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <h3 class="wt1">2. Dostosuj drzwiczki</h3>

            <div class="block">
              <p class="iblock">Pozycja klamki</p>

              <div class="text_input iblock ml150">
                <div class="block">
                  <a class="iblock tdn" style="margin-right:4px; margin-left: 7px;">
                    <input id="kl1" class="kl" type="radio" name="kl" value="lewa" checked>

                    <p class="q" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Lewa</p>
                  </a>
                  <a class="iblock tdn">
                    <input id="kl2" class="kl" type="radio" name="kl" value="prawa">

                    <p class="q" style="color:#696969;">Prawa</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearbox"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="block">
              <p class="iblock">Kolor drzwiczek</p>

              <div class="text_input iblock ml150">
                <div class="block">
                  <input id="ko1" class="ko" type="radio" name="ko" value="ko1" checked>
                  <div id="b1a" class="b1" data-name="czerń"><span style="border: 2px solid white;"></span></div>

                  <input id="ko2" class="ko" type="radio" name="ko" value="ko2">
                  <div id="b1b" class="b1" data-name="grafit"><span></span></div>

                  <input id="ko3" class="ko" type="radio" name="ko" value="ko3">
                  <div id="b1c" class="b1" data-name="czerwień"><span></span></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearbox"></div>
            </div>

            <h3 class="wt1">3. Dostosuj dodatki</h3>

            <div class="block m1">
              <p class="iblock m1">Rodzaj gałek</p>

              <div class="iblock" style="margin-left: 260px;">
                <input id="rkl1" class="rkl" type="radio" name="rkl" value="rkl1" checked>

                <div id="r1a" class="r1" data-name="gałka okrągła">
                  <img src="images/ikona_1.png" style="border: 2px solid white; border-radius: 18px;"/>
                </div>
                <input id="rkl2" class="rkl" type="radio" name="rkl" value="rkl2">

                <div id="r1b" class="r1" data-name="gałka kwadratowa">
                  <img src="images/ikona_2.png"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearbox"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="block">
              <p class="iblock">Rodzaj klamki</p>

              <div class="iblock gf12" style="margin-left: 250px; margin-right: 20px;">
                <input id="rka2" class="rka" type="radio" name="rka" value="rka2" checked>
                <p id="r2b" class="r2" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Okrągła</p>

                <input id="rka1" class="rka" type="radio" name="rka" value="rka1">
                <p id="r2a" class="r2" style="color:#696969; margin-left: 8px;">Kwadratowa</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="block">
              <p class="iblock">Wielkość klamki</p>
              <div class="iblock handle-size">
                <div class="block">
                  <a class="iblock tdn first-qq" style="margin-left: 239px;">
                    <input id="kls1" class="kls" type="radio" name="kls" value="kls1" checked>
                    <p class="qq" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" data-name="długość 125mm; fi 15mm / bok 15mm">Mała</p>
                  </a>

                  <a class="iblock tdn">
                    <input id="kls2" class="kls" type="radio" name="kls" value="kls2" checked>
                    <p class="qq" style="color:#696969;" data-name="długość 140mm; fi 20mm / bok 20mm">Duża</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearbox"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="block m2">
              <p class="iblock">Kolor dodatków</p>

              <div class="text_input iblock ml100">
                <div class="block">
                  <input id="kd1" class="kd" type="radio" name="kd" value="kd1" checked>
                  <div id="c11a" class="c11" data-name="czerń"><span style="border: 2px solid white;"></span></div>

                  <input id="kd3" class="kd" type="radio" name="kd" value="kd3">
                  <div id="c11c" class="c11" data-name="grafit"><span></span></div>

                  <input id="kd2" class="kd" type="radio" name="kd" value="kd2">
                  <div id="c11b" class="c11" data-name="stal nierdzewna"><span></span></div>

                  <input id="kd4" class="kd" type="radio" name="kd" value="kd4">
                  <div id="c11d" class="c11" data-name="mosiądz"><span></span></div>

                  <input id="kd6" class="kd" type="radio" name="kd" value="kd6">
                  <div id="c11f" class="c11" data-name="czerwień"><span></span></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearbox"></div>
            </div>

            <h3 class="wt1">4. Wybierz modyfikacje dodatkowe</h3>

            <div class="block">
              <p class="iblock">Drzwiczki zamykane automatycznie</p>

              <div class="text_input iblock doors_auto" style="margin-left:117px;">
                <div class="block">
                  <a class="iblock tdn" style="margin-right:4px;">
                    <input id="a1" class="a" type="radio" name="a" value="a1">

                    <p class="qqq" style="color:#696969;">Tak</p>
                  </a>
                  <a class="iblock tdn">
                    <input id="a2" class="a" type="radio" name="a" value="a2" checked>

                    <p class="qqq" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Nie</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearbox"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="block">
              <p class="iblock">Maskownica (paski maskujące)</p>

              <div class="text_input iblock doors_mask" style="margin-left:154px;">
                <div class="block">
                  <a class="iblock tdn" style="margin-right:4px;">
                    <input id="aa1" class="aa" type="radio" name="aa" value="aa1">

                    <p class="qqqq" style="color:#696969;">Tak</p>
                  </a>
                  <a class="iblock tdn">
                    <input id="aa2" class="aa" type="radio" name="aa" value="aa2" checked>

                    <p class="qqqq" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Nie</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearbox"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="block">
              <p class="iblock">Szyba samoczyszcząca</p>

              <div class="text_input iblock doors_glass" style="margin-left:213px;">
                <div class="block">
                  <a class="iblock tdn" style="margin-right:4px;">
                    <input id="aaa1" class="aaa" type="radio" name="aaa" value="aaa1">

                    <p class="qqqqq" style="color:#696969;">Tak</p>
                  </a>
                  <a class="iblock tdn">
                    <input id="aaa2" class="aaa checked" type="radio" name="aaa" value="aaa2" checked>

                    <p class="qqqqq" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Nie</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearbox">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="block">
              <p class="iblock">Listwy zdobiące</p>

              <div class="text_input iblock doors_bar" style="margin-left:266px;">
                <div class="block">
                  <a class="iblock tdn" style="margin-right:4px;">
                    <input id="aaaa1" class="aaaa" type="radio" name="aaaa" value="aaaa1">

                    <p class="qqqqqq" style="color:#696969;">Tak</p>
                  </a>
                  <a class="iblock tdn marg20nr">
                    <input id="aaaa2" class="aaaa checked" type="radio" name="aaaa" value="aaaa2" checked>

                    <p class="qqqqqq" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Nie</p>
                  </a>

                  <input id="fq1" class="fq" type="radio" name="fq" value="fq1">

                  <div id="fqqf1" class="fqqf iblock" data-name="aluminium"><span></span></div>

                  <input id="fq2" class="fq" type="radio" name="fq" value="fq2">

                  <div id="fqqf2" class="fqqf iblock" data-name="mosiądz"><span></span></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearbox"></div>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="door_name" value="<?php echo $name ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="door" value="<?php echo $door ?>">

            <h3 class="wt1">5. Uzupełnij dane kontaktowe</h3>
            <div class="block phone-block">
              <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Twój telefon" required>
            </div>

            <div class="block submit-block">
              <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Twój e-mail" required>
              <label for="message">Uwagi:</label>
              <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
              <button class="send">Wyślij
                <img src="images/arrow4.png">
              </button>
            </div>

            <div class="block form-response">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 mod">
          <img src="images/doors_sizes/<?php echo $door ?>.png"/>
          <p class="image-info">Zamieszczone zdjęcia na stronie internetowej mogą nieznacznie różnić się od rzeczywistego wyglądu produktu.</p>

          <?php if ($door != 'ax6_panorama' && $door != 'ax6_popielnik'): ?>
          <div class="text-area-dark text-left price-block">
            <div style="width: 100%;">
              <h2 style="float:left; margin-top: 18px;">Koszt całkowity:</h2>

              <div style="float: right;">
                <h1 class="yPrice" style="margin-top: 0;"><?php if ($isSimple) echo 595; else echo 695; ?> zł</h1>

                <p class="redp">(minimalna cena drzwiczek)</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="individual-evaluation">
              <p>Wybrane modyfikacje wymagają indywidualnej wyceny.<br>Prosimy wypełnić oraz przesłać formularz.</p>
          </div>
          <?php else: ?>
          <div class="text-area-dark text-left price-block doors-on-phone">
            <div style="width: 100%;">
              <p>Wybrane drzwi wymagają indywidualnej wyceny.<br>Prosimy wypełnić oraz przesłać formularz.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="about-form col-md-12">
          <p>
            <span>Powyższy formularz nie jest równoznaczny z zakupem drzwiczek.</span> Ma on na celu przybliżenie Państwu
            całkowitego kosztu wybranego modelu wraz z modyfikacjami. Po wypełnieniu i przesłaniu formularza, jeden
            z
            naszych pracowników skontaktuje się z Państwem jak najszybciej i pomoże rozwiać wszelkie wątpliwości
            związane z zakupem.
          </p>
          <p>Podana cena nie stanowi oferty handlowej w rozumieniu Art. 66 par. 1 Kodeksu Cywilnego i może ulec zmianie.</p>
          <p>
            Cena minimalna jednych drzwiczek nie może być mniejsza niż <?php if($isSimple) echo 595; else echo 695; ?> zł brutto.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    if ($door == 'ad3_proste1' || $door == 'ax6_proste1' || $door == 'af3_proste1' || $door == 'af3_proste2') {
    $isSimple = true;
  }

  $basePrice = 0;

  if ($door == 'ad3_proste1')
    $basePrice = 27;
  else if ($door == 'af3_proste1' || $door == 'af3_proste2')
    $basePrice = 29;
  else if ($door == 'ax6_proste1')
    $basePrice = 29;
  else if ($door == 'ad3_boczna')
    $basePrice = 29;
  else if ($door == 'af3_boczna')
    $basePrice = 31;
  else if ($door == 'ax6_boczna')
    $basePrice = 31;
  else if ($door == 'ad3_luk')
    $basePrice = 32;
  else if ($door == 'af3_luk')
    $basePrice = 34;
  else if ($door == 'ax6_luk')
    $basePrice = 34;
  else if ($door == 'ad3_pol')
    $basePrice = 32;
  else if ($door == 'af3_pol')
    $basePrice = 34;
  else if ($door == 'ax6_pol')
    $basePrice = 34;
  else if ($door == 'ax6_pryzma')
    $basePrice = 36;

  $isC = false;
  $isD = false;

  if ($door == 'ad3_boczna' || $door == 'af3_boczna' || $door == 'ax6_boczna' || $door == 'ax6_pryzma') {
    $isC = true;
  }
```

Comment: And.... where's the code?

Comment: put some codes , the community is here to help you , not to dig into you code .

Comment: You have a missing "$" in line 745. And the capitan letter of "Helluva" in line 630 must be red.

Comment: Free tip: https://www.ebooks-it.net/ebook/clean-code